# 56:68: error: expected expression

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to understand the last argument of find_if which is giving compilation errors.  Any pointers on documentation in the context of this problem on the usage of  [](int ch)  will be really helpful. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Seeing compilation error with one of the argument.

https://leetcode.com/playground/U5SLW8zq

> median.cpp:56:68: error: expected expression
>       input.erase(input.begin(), find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](int ch) {
>                                                                      ^ median.cpp:62:55: error: expected expression
>       input.erase(find_if(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), [](int ch) {

```
void trimLeftTrailingSpaces(string &input) {
    input.erase(input.begin(), find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](int ch) {
        return !isspace(ch);
    }));
}

void trimRightTrailingSpaces(string &input) {
    input.erase(find_if(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), [](int ch) {
        return !isspace(ch);
    }).base(), input.end());
}
```

Comment: Please pare the example program down to minimal size. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you. I will update the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the missing compiler option. I could compile using c++11

$ g++ -std=c++11  median.cpp